# Entity form Submissions automatic numbering over 1000

Tags: forms, entities

I have reach an entity form submission count that has hit 1,000.

The problem I have is the URL is '/entityform/1,000' - notice the comma. This screws up the link to the url. I have searched and cannot find how to remove the comma when entityform creates the link.

I have check alias patterns, module settings and every where else I can look within the drupal/module configuration.

Can someone help me figure out where to make this update?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay after searching it was probably the 12 forum post I found another module that helps with this issue.

Install this module along with Pathauto.
https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_entity

The URL Alias is: [entityform:type:label]/[entityform:entityform-id]

Hopefully that helps someone.
Peace

Comment: Actually this didn't solve it. DOH!